# Steam Cloud with two Steam accounts on one Windows account

Tags: steam, steam-cloud

My boyfriend and I both play most of our games through Steam. I recently wanted to play a game that we both own on his desktop, logged into his Windows account, but using my Steam account and getting my save file from the Steam Cloud.

When I started up the game, however, the Cloud gave me two options:

- Sync the Cloud to this computer and the current save file (ie my  boyfriend's account save file); or
- Sync the computer's save file to the Cloud and thus erase my personal save file.

Is it in any way possible for two accounts to use the Cloud independently on one Windows account?

**Update**

Using multiple accounts seems the be the obvious answer here, but while it works for some games which store save files in a sane way (in user directories), a lot of Steam games have their files in a global location in Steamapps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming his backups were working correctly (backup after every session), it should be safe to overwrite his save with yours, then let him overwrite yours when he wants to play.

The easier and safer option would be to use separate Windows accounts, but older games tend to store the saves in their install folder instead of your Users folder, putting you back at square one.

Comment: By "backup" do you mean the sync to the cloud, i.e. each player overwrites the save file from the cloud every time they swap in? If so, how do you verify everything's been synced properly?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Launching and closing the game in question should ensure his saves are synced. Of course, this is still a needlessly perilous situation, you should consider using a separate Windows account.

Comment: This sort of thing is exactly why multiple Windows accounts are possible and should be used.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Well, yes, but... we just tried with separate Windows accounts and the same problem occurs. Seems like Steam hasn't followed your advice?

Comment: Are you sure it has? Perhaps Steam is simply asking if you want to download your saves from the cloud for the new account.

Comment: His local saves are part of his Windows login; his cloud saves are part of his Steam account. It should be impossible (barring black-hat security exploits) to overwrite his local or cloud saves from a separate Windows login and separate Steam login.

Comment: It looks like that's true for some games but not all? For example, Steam Cloud syncs my Psychonauts saves, but it stores them inside steam/steamapps, not in my user directory. Maybe the real question is if it's possible to do avoid overwriting for games like that.

Comment: If the game has been made to save in its installer folder instead of a Users directory then there isn't much you can do.

Comment: Most Steam games seem to be that way, except Valve games, from what I can tell.

Comment: Most old games are that way, while most (if not all) new games aren't.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, if you edit the important bits from the comments into your answer, I'll gladly accept it!

Comment: Done. Charlimit.